# Adding items to ChoiceBox<?>

Tags: java, javafx-2

in class `DataConstantsNames` I have:

```
public static final ObservableList<Object> IMPORTVARIABLES = FXCollections.observableArrayList(DATE, TIME, new Separator(),OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, new Separator(),VOLUME);
```

I would like to add these variables to a choiceBox in class controller where I have 7 choiceBoxes:

```
ChoiceBox[] columnName = {choiceboxColumn1, choiceboxColumn2, choiceboxColumn3, choiceboxColumn4, choiceboxColumn5, choiceboxColumn6, choiceboxColumn7};
```

My question: If I do a for loop such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < columnName.length; i++) {
    columnName[i].setItems(DataConstantsName.IMPORTVARIABLES);
}
```

Everything is fine, but if I try to set items to a single choiceBox, I get this error:

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what type does `choiceboxColumn1` have?

Comment: I am using the standard choiceBox from SceneBuilder 1.1, just did drag and drop from SceneBuilder -> Library.

Comment: and what did SceneBuider generate for `choiceboxColumn1`?

Comment: In controller class: <br/>
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<?> choiceboxColumn1;

In .fxml:  <ChoiceBox id="choicebox1" fx:id="choiceboxColumn1" minHeight="17.0" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="62.0">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why SB generated your ChoiceBox with a wildcard (`<?>`), but you can't set items in a wildcarded lists without type specification.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html for more details.

To make your code compilable either remove wildcards from ChoiceBoxes:

```
@FXML private ChoiceBox choiceboxColumn1;
```

or cast variable to specific type:

```
((ChoiceBox)choiceboxColumn1).setItems(IMPORTVARIABLES);
```

or

```
((ChoiceBox<Object>)choiceboxColumn1).setItems(IMPORTVARIABLES);
```

**P.S.:** `for` loop worked for you because you put `choiceboxColumn1` into array of plain `ChoiceBox`. By this you said to compiler to ignore all generics and work with variables in old, java 1.4, style.

You may achieve that using direct set:

```
ChoiceBox cb = choiceboxColumn1;
cb.setItems(IMPORTVARIABLES);
```

You can do it due to Java type erasure concept: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: Thank you very much, by casting to (ChoiceBox) it all now works and compile. It remains a mistery to me why using a for loop there was no need to cast.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, now it is all clear to me.